# Div goes beyond page limits

Tags: html, css

Can't figure out why it's too tall, sorry:

```
html {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

body {
    height:100%;
    background-color:darkblue;
    background-image:url(background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#wrapper {
    width:65%;
    top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
    background-color:#bad6e8;
    border:2px solid black;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background-color:#bad6e8;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    padding:2px;
}

#user {
    width:25%;
    height:250px;
    background-color:#bad6e8;
    border-right:2px solid black;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    float:left;
    padding:2px;
}

#menu {
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
    background-color:#bad6e8;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    padding:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

and:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Playdux</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                Header
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="user">
                    Usermenu
                </div>
                <div id="menu">
                    Menü
                </div>
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "wrapper" div should go all the way from the top of the page to the bottom. Stopping there, unless it has enough content to go beyond that.

But, without enough content, it's just way over the limit. My CSS is kinda messed up now because I tried to figure it out all the time.

Comment: it would help to make a jsfiddle for these to help visualise what's going on.. here, I've made one for you: http://jsfiddle.net/bUE4M/

Comment: Looks like you'd do well to use tables.... or css display:table;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the `wrapper` from top to bottom, you must `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`

```
#wrapper {
    width:65%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
    background-color:#bad6e8;
    border:2px solid black;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You must also remove [`height: 100%`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property) from `content`. Because this is interpreted as 100% of the containing block, which is `wrapper` in this case

```
#content {
    width:100%;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

See full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpBS5/1/)

Another way to do this, would be dropping `top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;`
 and do just `height: 100%`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
```

See another [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpBS5/2/)